# why does the indentation get mixed up when I hit save on my vscode

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, indentation

So I am currently learning react by going to the official reactjs.org and am currently making a tic tac toe game as instructed. I am using vscode as my editor. What happened is that when I copied the code from the site(as instructed) and pasted it on my editor, when I hit save, the indentation gets all mixed up, there are tags everywhere. The code works as intended but it's not readable at all. Even when I manually fix some lines of codes, when I hit save , the code goes everywhere. Please help me fix this. This is getting really annoying :(

Comment: You probably set VS code to autoformat on save. Either disable the setting or change the default format to the one you actually want.

Comment: This happened to be when both eslint and prettier where enabled with incompatible settings.

Comment: I have actually unchecked the autoformat on save setting.

Answer (score 2):

you can go to settings ( ctrl + ,) type "Format on Save" and uncheck the "AutoSave" box

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is caused by some following reasons:

- You install several code-beautify extensions, they get conflicts. Try to uninstall and restart if requires
- Go to vscode settings (the one with the gear) and check if Format on Save is set to true...
- besides you can search from the settings some keywords like indent....

Comment: I am not sure what code-beautify extensions actually are but I think I have installed theme extension , oceanic next or sth like that. 
I have unchecked the format on save setting.
I will try searching from the settings. Anyway, thatnks for responding.